# InvokeCommandAction isn't invoking the templatebinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, interactive

I'm attempting to make a reusable control that display an image binded by TemplateBinding and that is interactive, supporting eventually stuff like right clicking, middle clicking, left clicking, via Commands for binding with the view model. It will also support multiple overlays, as a result this control inherits from ItemsControl.

However the SomeViewModel's MouseLeftButtonDownCommand isn't being invoked. I wrote some test ChangePropertyAction in Generic.xaml and it does trigger the action properly, so it's something I'm doing wrong with the command hook up.

Here's the code (sorry for being so long)

In my Themes\Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom_ContentControl"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                <Grid Background="Red">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{TemplateBinding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}" />
                            <!--<ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="Image" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />-->
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In my CustomControl.cs

```
namespace Custom_ContentControl
{
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

public class CustomControl : ItemsControl
{
    static CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MouseLeftButtonDownCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand MouseLeftButtonDownCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(MouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Custom_ContentControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:customContentControl="clr-namespace:Custom_ContentControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance customContentControl:SomeViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <customContentControl:CustomControl ImageSource="Resources/sample.jpg"
                                        MouseLeftButtonDownCommand="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}">
        <!--<TextBlock Text="Some sample text" Foreground="White" />-->
    </customContentControl:CustomControl>
</Grid>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace Custom_ContentControl
{
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
    }
}

class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand mouseLeftButtonDownCommand;

    public RelayCommand MouseLeftButtonDownCommand
    {
        get { return mouseLeftButtonDownCommand ?? (mouseLeftButtonDownCommand = new RelayCommand(OnMouseLeftButtonDown)); }
    }

    private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
    }
}
}
```

Note that this project depends on MvvmLight nuget package along with Expression.Blend.Sdk.

How would I properly hook up my ViewModel command so that it is invoked by a mouse left button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `Binding` slightly in Generic.xaml to

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

this will now Bind to the Dependency Property in your CustomControl correctly
Hope it helps

Comment: It does help, thanks a lot. Would you know why `TemplateBinding` doesn't work with `EventTrigger`? Because if I add a button right after the Image with `<Button Width="100" Height="25" Command="{TemplateBinding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}" />` the button command gets hooked up as expected.

Comment: Yes that will work in firing the ViewModel Command as the DataContext of MainWindow is the ViewModel, it invokes the ViewModel Command but NOT the CustomControls MouseLeftButtonDown DependencyProperty. EventTrigger fires in both scenerios but only the first is picked up by your CustomControl DP.